# How to get ID value from the previous page and insert it in the next page

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a **locator** to an **account holder** the image at **AddLocator.php** is the **account holder**.
The link **Add Locator** redirects the user to the **AddLocatorProcess.php**. What I need is get the **ID**  of the **account holder** to insert it in the newly created **locator** as a foreign key.
How would i do that?

**AddLocator.php**
[image]

**AddLocatorProcess.php**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `Add Locator` href so that it includes the ID in URL, something like this:

```
<a href="AddLocatorProcess.php?id=<ID_TO_BE_SENT_ON_NEXT_PAGE>">Add Locator</a>
```

Then in AddLocatorProcess.php page you can get that ID as:

```
<?php echo $_GET['id']; //this will give the id of clicked locator to be used as foreign key?>
```